# Python,sklearn,it-idf how to split by "####",default space

Tags: python, split, scikit-learn, tf-idf

use sklean tf-idf,the defult use space split

```
corpus = [  
'This is the first document.',  
'This is the second second document.',  
'And the third one.',  
'Is this the first document?'
]    

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()   
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

but,I want to use this form:

```
enter code herecorpus = [  
'This####is####the####first####document.',  
'This####is####the####second####second####document.'
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()   
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
tfidf=transformer.fit_transform(vectorizer.fit_transform(documents))
word=vectorizer.get_feature_names()
weight=tfidf.toarray()
```

How to do?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html pass your own tokenizer

Answer (score 5):

Use a custom tokenizer:

```
def four_pounds_tokenizer(s):
   return s.split('####')

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=four_pounds_tokenizer)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```